# How can I get data from this Amazon XML response file using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

How can I extract the values from the Amazon MWS XML file shown below?

Sadly I'm not very good with PHP (or XML). I have been reading/trying everything I can find on all sites I can find but I think I'm just not up to the job.

I've tried DOM, simpleXML, namespaces etc etc but must have simply got it all wrong.

I've tried this snippet of code:

```
    $response = $service->GetMyPriceForASIN($request);

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->saveXML();     

    $x = $dom->documentElement;
    foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item) {
    print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
    }
```

However it only returns this data from the outermost nodes, shown here:

> GetMyPriceForASINResult = xxxxxxxxxxxB07DNYLZP5USD9.97USD9.97USD0.00USD15.99AMAZONNewNewxxxxxxxxxxxxxDazzle Tattoos
>   ResponseMetadata = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

What I'm simply trying to get are the currency and prices that are the children under the [Offers] node.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMyPriceForASINResponse 
xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
  <GetMyPriceForASINResult ASIN="B07DNYLZP5" status="Success">
    <Product>
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>B07DNYLZP5</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
      </Identifiers>
      <Offers>
        <Offer>
          <BuyingPrice>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>9.97</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>9.97</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>0.00</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </BuyingPrice>
          <RegularPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>15.99</Amount>
          </RegularPrice>
          <FulfillmentChannel>AMAZON</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
          <SellerId>xxxxxxxxxx</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>Dazzle Tattoos</SellerSKU>
        </Offer>
      </Offers>
    </Product>
  </GetMyPriceForASINResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetMyPriceForASINResponse>
```

### Update

The link provided by Nigel doesn't help - it is basically a compendium of information.

Comment: you have to check that if $x->nodeName=='CurrencyCode' or Price.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Hi Kaushik - yes but the problem is it only finds the outer nodes so I can't check th others - it doesn't get that far down the tree.

Comment: Hi Nigel - yes it is a possible duplicate - however I've read everything and am still stuck so I'm hoping someone will help.

Comment: Read a little bit about Xpath, you can use it with [DOMXpath::evaluate()](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php). It allows you to use expressions to fetch nodes/values from a DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML *in general* is fairly easy to work with, but you've stumbled over one of the things that makes it much tricker: XML namespaces. This is given away by the presence of the `xmlns` attribute in the outer element.

My first thought upon looking at your document was, and since I am not familiar with this API, "offers" sounds like it could be plural. I therefore modified the test document to allow for that, since `<Offers>` is probably designed to contain zero, one, or more than one `<Offer>`.

So, for testing purposes, that would look like this (I've just duplicated the single `<Offer>` for convenience):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GetMyPriceForASINResponse 
    xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01"
>
  <GetMyPriceForASINResult ASIN="B07DNYLZP5" status="Success">
    <Product>
      <Identifiers>
        <MarketplaceASIN>
          <MarketplaceId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</MarketplaceId>
          <ASIN>B07DNYLZP5</ASIN>
        </MarketplaceASIN>
      </Identifiers>
      <Offers>
        <Offer>
          <BuyingPrice>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>9.97</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>9.97</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>0.00</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </BuyingPrice>
          <RegularPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>15.99</Amount>
          </RegularPrice>
          <FulfillmentChannel>AMAZON</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
          <SellerId>xxxxxxxxxx</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>Dazzle Tattoos</SellerSKU>
        </Offer>
        <Offer>
          <BuyingPrice>
            <LandedPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>9.97</Amount>
            </LandedPrice>
            <ListingPrice>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>9.97</Amount>
            </ListingPrice>
            <Shipping>
              <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
              <Amount>0.00</Amount>
            </Shipping>
          </BuyingPrice>
          <RegularPrice>
            <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
            <Amount>15.99</Amount>
          </RegularPrice>
          <FulfillmentChannel>AMAZON</FulfillmentChannel>
          <ItemCondition>New</ItemCondition>
          <ItemSubCondition>New</ItemSubCondition>
          <SellerId>xxxxxxxxxx</SellerId>
          <SellerSKU>Dazzle Tattoos</SellerSKU>
        </Offer>
      </Offers>
    </Product>
  </GetMyPriceForASINResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</GetMyPriceForASINResponse>
```

The PHP code I used is as follows. I've used `SimpleXML` here, as I am familiar with it, but I expect there would be a `DOMDocument` solution as well.

```
<?php

$file = 'prices.xml';
$doc = simplexml_load_file($file);

// Examine the namespaces
$namespaces = $doc->getNamespaces(true);    
print_r($namespaces);

$nsDoc = $doc->children($namespaces['']);
$nsDoc->registerXPathNamespace('p', 'http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01');

$nodes = $nsDoc->xpath('//p:GetMyPriceForASINResult/p:Product/p:Offers/p:Offer');
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    print_r($node);
}
```

My first `print_r` will show you the namespaces you have in your document, and the only one you have is the null namespace. Since this is empty, your tags are not prefixed with a string (e.g. `Amazon:Product`) but the namespace nevertheless still exists. That looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [] => http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01
)
```

I then get a namespaced version of the document (`$doc->children($namespaces[''])`) to work with. I have also declared the name of the namespace to be `p` (using `registerXPathNamespace`) which is an arbitrary name - you can use anything here that makes sense to you. (I did try registering a null name (`''`) but this did not work).

Finally, I use XPath as suggested in the comments, but since the namespace applies to the parent and all its children, I have added my namespace alias in front of every tag. (XPath is basically a query language for XML, and an explanation of it requires a book or a manual, so I will refrain from digging in too deeply here. If you are going to be doing more than a cursory bit of XML, I recommend finding an XML test application on the web and trying out some queries).

The output produces the two (identical) `<Offer>` nodes, which are thus:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [BuyingPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [LandedPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                    [Amount] => 9.97
                )

            [ListingPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                    [Amount] => 9.97
                )

            [Shipping] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                    [Amount] => 0.00
                )

        )

    [RegularPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [CurrencyCode] => USD
            [Amount] => 15.99
        )

    [FulfillmentChannel] => AMAZON
    [ItemCondition] => New
    [ItemSubCondition] => New
    [SellerId] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [SellerSKU] => Dazzle Tattoos
)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [BuyingPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [LandedPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                    [Amount] => 9.97
                )

            [ListingPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                    [Amount] => 9.97
                )

            [Shipping] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [CurrencyCode] => USD
                    [Amount] => 0.00
                )

        )

    [RegularPrice] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [CurrencyCode] => USD
            [Amount] => 15.99
        )

    [FulfillmentChannel] => AMAZON
    [ItemCondition] => New
    [ItemSubCondition] => New
    [SellerId] => xxxxxxxxxx
    [SellerSKU] => Dazzle Tattoos
)
```

You will want to dereference items within each node too. To do that, you can use object references and then casting to the type you want. For example:

```
$fulfillment = (string) $node->FulfillmentChannel;
echo "$fulfillment\n";
```

In the loop, this will produce the values we expect:

```
AMAZON
AMAZON
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!  This has helped me so much.  I appreciate you taking the time to do this for me.

Comment: No worries @TheTerribleProgrammer, you are welcome. If you are keen on getting some practice, you could convert it to `DOMDocument` now you know what the issue is. This might be a good idea also if you have used `DOMDocument` elsewhere in your code - in general, you don't want to use more than one library to do the same thing. However, if you just want to get it working, use this one. `:-)`

Comment: (I fought with a financial API a couple of years back, and they just _love_ their XML namespaces!)